# Losing Audiofocus

Tags: android, audio

i wrote a podcast audio player and included the audio focus principle.

This is my method, which is called in the onPrepared() method of the media player:

```
private boolean requestAudioFocus(){

    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT){
                pause();
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                play();
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                Log.d("MYAUDIOSERVICE","Audio Focus lost");
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    // Request audio focus for playback
    int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                                     // Use the music stream.
                                     AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                     // Request permanent focus.
                                     AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is:

Everything works finde when starting the app and playing the first podcast. Audiofocus is gained and the podcast keeps playing.

When i stop playback and start another podcast the audiofocus is gained again, but shortly after AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS is receiver by the onAudioFocusChangeListener.

I guess thats the case because my app has the focus, request it again, gains it but at the same time loses the "old" one.

Am i right, and if if thats correct, can i just give up the audio focus when ending playback on the old podcast ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Got it myself. Didnt abandon the audio focus correctly, so when i request it again i simultaniously lose the old one and changeListener is called